# excel, subtract days from original date to get business days only

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have business date `20/07/2018` , I want to subtract days but only get business dates.
Currently I am getting `19/07/2018` when I subtract 1.

Anyone know how to get business dates only?

Comment: and why would you not get the 19th.  The 20th is Friday so subtracting one day would land on a business day.  Is it a holiday for your locale?

Comment: Not a holiday, but I want to fill down in a column. So the next day would be 18th, 17th, this would get weekends, which I don't want.

Comment: Is [this](https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/1954-excel-fill-weekdays.html) what you're looking for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use WORKDAY.INTL(), you can even define holidays and what are weekends:

```
=WORKDAY.INTL(A2,-1,1,$F$2:$F$4)
```

The `1` assumes Saturday/Sunday as weekends and I put a list of holidays in `$F$2:$F$4` which will also be skipped.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

To do this you can use

`=WORKDAYS(start_date; end_date; [holidays])`

In your case, you should use it like this

`=WORKDAYS(STARTING_DATE; -ndays)` where `ndays` is an integer representing the date difference

This will give you a serial date, which you can convert with Format->Short Date (or whatever you like)

Cheers

EDIT: You can pass a range of days(holydays dates) as your third parametre, which will cause the formula to skip said dates, as they may be holydays in your country, but not in others.

EDIT: ScottCranner was right, `DIAS.LAB()` is `NETWORKINGDAYS()` and `DIA.LAB()` is `WORKDAYS()`, I did miss translate the functions. Now is correct

Comment: @ScottCraner It works in Excel 2010 in Spanish, I've used this `=DIA.LAB("20/11/2018";-2)` yields `"16/11/2018"`. `=DIA.LAB()` is equivalent to `=NEWTWORKINGDAYS`

Comment: @ScottCraner Yes, you are right. Spanish is a funny thing you know, miss one "s" and suddenly in english you have a whole word attached to something.

Answer (score 1):

In B2
=WORKDAY(A2,-5,Holiday!C15:C24)

this worked. its date from A2 and subtracting 5 days if its not a Holiday or weekend.

how can show B2 field empty if A2 has no value?